# Remove Wrap Text from Access Query

Tags: excel, ms-access, xlsx, word-wrap

I'm currently changing an access function so that instead of `.xls` files, it exports `.xlsx`. After completing this, the only formatting issue was that a wrap text was applied on all the cells exported (not sure if this is something that comes with converting to `.xlsx`)

I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the wrap text while the file is still in excel, or if there's a command I can add to my export query to make the cells not wrap text.

The command I use to create the data in Access is:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Device Summary", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

Then I export it to an .xlsx file

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Device Summary", acFormatXLSX, Forms![BuildSheet]![Text2] & "-Summary.xlsx", True
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the Access table column widths wide enough to display the data and then the export adopted those column widths. Save the query object with the column widths set.

Why objection to wrapped text?

There is actually no need to open the query object to export.

Comment: What do you mean by "save the query with the column widths set"? Some of the fields being exported are multiple lines long and have a lot of characters, so I would rather not have super-long column widths.

Comment: Then might have to accept the wrapping otherwise the Excel columns would be super-long or text appear to cut off, even though it's really in the cell.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for - the cells to be cut off rather than expand to be shown.

Comment: Unfortunately, appears to be feature of xlsx because I tested xls and does not wrap. Don't see an optional parameter. Sorry, think you are stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

After the word `True` at the end, specify a blank template file you would like to use.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Device Summary", acFormatXLSX, Forms![BuildSheet]![Text2] & "-Summary.xlsx", True, "C:\Template.xlsx"
```

And make sure that template file has wrap turned off for the entire sheet.

Comment: I'll try this out, although the query will be ran by multiple users with local copies of this access file, so if the wrap could be specified in the export statement rather than replying on a local template - that would be ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible.